# Can Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.1 be used with Microsoft ODBC Driver 1.0?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, odbc, jdbc-odbc

I need to upgrade `sqljdbc4.jar` to `sqljdbc41.jar`.

Microsoft website has the following information:

> sqljdbc41.jar class library provides support for JDBC 4.0 API. It includes all of the features of the JDBC 4.0 driver as well as the JDBC 4.0 API methods. JDBC 4.1 is not supported (will throw an exception “SQLFeatureNotSupportedException”).

Thus, the already running JDBC APIs in java will work properly.

But, the Microsoft ODBC Driver 1.0 must be compatible with Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.1

Can  [Microsoft ODBC Driver 1.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=28160)   be used with  [Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54670)  ?

Also, if java applications will use JDBC only to connect to the Microsoft SQL Server  and any other language application needs to use ODBC to connect to the database  then when is JDBC-ODBC bridge used?

[image: JDBC-ODBC bridge]

---

System specifications:

Linux: 64bit Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4

ODBC on linux:  unixODBC 2.3.0 Driver Manager

Application: Only Java Application

Comment: A JDBC driver is for connecting to a SQL Server database from a Java application (or at least an application running in the JVM), it has nothing to do with ODBC: it does not use ODBC nor can it be used from ODBC.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to better explain what you want to accomplish. As @MarkRotteveel says, the JDBC driver is all you need to manipulate a SQL Server database from a Java application. Do you have another non-Java application that needs to use the ODBC driver, and, if so, are you concerned that the two applications might conflict with each other somehow? BTW, your ODBC driver link is for a *very* (>5 year) old version.

Comment: Yes, ODBC 1.0   will be changed in future. I have edited the question. What about JDBC-ODBC bridge?  If java applications will use JDBC only to connect to the Microsoft SQL Server  and any other language application needs to use ODBC to connect to the database  then when is JDBC-ODBC bridge used?

Comment: Why introduce the JDBC/ODBC bridge to your question if you have a perfectly fine pure JDBC driver to use? Academic curiosity? Know that the bridge was always intended as a transitional measure, and it has been removed from Java 8.

Comment: Okay, so odbc seems to be not used as my application does not have  sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver  .   I did not know that JDBC/ODBC bridge  was a transitional measure  and have become obsolete in  JDK 8

Answer (score 1):

> when is JDBC-ODBC bridge used?

The short answer is "Not very much any more" because the JDBC-ODBC Bridge was removed from Java 8.

The JDBC-ODBC Bridge was intended to be a *transitional* way for Java applications to work with databases that had an ODBC driver but did not (yet) have a JDBC driver. The JDBC-ODBC Bridge was never really intended for production use and, in fact, was never officially supported.